# Maven says archetype does not exist

Tags: maven, jpa

I am trying to create a JPA based project using Maven and eclipse. I tried using the jpa-maven-archetype from create new maven project in the eclipse project creation, but it shot back this error

```
Could not resolve archetype com.rfc.maven.archetypes:jpa-maven-archetype:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact com.rfc.maven.archetypes:jpa-maven-archetype:pom:RELEASE
Failed to resolve version for com.rfc.maven.archetypes:jpa-maven-archetype:pom:RELEASE:   Could not find metadata com.rfc.maven.archetypes:jpa-maven-archetype/maven-metadata.xml in local (/home/sebastian/.m2/repository) 
Failed to resolve version for com.rfc.maven.archetypes:jpa-maven-archetype:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata com.rfc.maven.archetypes:jpa-maven-archetype/maven-metadata.xml in local (/home/sebastian/.m2/repository)
```

Basically the eclipse plugin is looking into my local repositories instead of remote ones. So I tried going the command line and explicitly specifying the remote repository with the following command

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:1.0-alpha-7:create \
  -DgroupId=com.something -DartifactId=jpaexample \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=jpa-maven-archetype \
  -DarchetypeVersion=RELEASE \
  -DremoteRepositories=http://maven.rodcoffin.com/repo \
  -DinteractiveMode=false
```

And I got this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:1.0-alpha-7:create (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Error creating from archetype: Error attempting to download archetype. Error downloading. Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:jpa-maven-archetype:jar:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:jpa-maven-archetype/maven-metadata.xml in local (/home/sebastian/.m2/repository)
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.archetypes:jpa-maven-archetype:jar:RELEASE
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] id0 (http://maven.rodcoffin.com/repo, releases=true, snapshots=true)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

It seems that repo maven.rodcoffin.com/repo is not working, or there is something wrong with my maven setup. I am not sure which one, if some one could give me pointers on where to search for, that would be helpful.

Also if repo maven.rodcoffin.com/repo is not working. What are my other options to create a JPA archetype project. Do I have to make a simple maven project and then convert it to a JPA as shown [here](http://www.javavids.com/video/jpa-project-using-hibernate-and-maven.html).

EDIT: I just weaseled out of the problem by creating a maven quick type achetype and then using the persistence.xml for my project.
So just ignore this question.